# Create element "in memory", like jQuery does, in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

Instead of doing

```
d3.select("body").append("svg")
```

, which most d3.js examples do, I'd like to create an element, and NOT attach it to body or anything right away.

Kind of like `$('<div/>')` in jQuery.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create "svg" object without appending it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455282/how-to-create-svg-object-without-appending-it)

Answer (score 22):

Create the element using [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) and pass it to `d3` as usual.

In console:

```
> a = document.createElement("div")
<div>​</div>​
> d3.select(a).append("svg")
[Array[1]]   
> a
<div>​
<svg>​</svg>​
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks @widged from the follow up!

Answer (score 9):

```
// create selection containing unattached div node    
var sel = d3.create('svg');
```

and if you want just the node...

```
// retrieve unattached node
var node = d3.create('svg').node();
```

Answer (score 2):

To create the svg element "in memory" use `document.createElementNS`.

**Use of document.createElementNS:**

```
// Create the svg elem
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");

// Create a g elem
var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");

// Create a d3 Selection with the elem
var d3Svg = d3.select(svg);
var d3g = d3.select(g);
```

**Append a d3 selection to another d3 selection:**

```
d3Svg.append(function(){ return d3g.node(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like:

```
var $svg = $('<svg/>');
var d3svg = d3.select($svg[0]);

// ... manipulate d3svg ...

$('body').append($svg)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in order to support percentage widths on my custom SVG element:

```
var svgDom = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svgDom.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
svg = d3.select(svgDom)
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%");
```