# d3 create object without appending

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using d3 for graphing, and I'm trying to create an svg object, to add to the DOM later.

I used to have

```
var svg = d3.select(el).append("svg");
var graph = svg.append("g")
...etc...
```

and for reasons I won't go into, I wanted to create the `svg` element before appending it to the DOM.

So I did

```
var svg = d3.select(document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, 'svg'))
var graph = svg.append("g")
...etc...
```

, which works, and while debugging, I can see that `svg` is a 1-element array, with the children nicely attached.

The problem comes at the `append` step:

```
d3.select(el).append(svg);
```

There, I get an error `Error: Failed to execute 'createElementNS' on 'Document': The qualified name provided ('[object SVGSVGElement]') contains the invalid name-start character '['.` I've taken a look here: [How to create "svg" object without appending it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455282/how-to-create-svg-object-without-appending-it) but it seems that's exactly how they suggest it.

Any idea why this is so? I've tried appending `svg[0]`, but no luck either. It seems `append()` only takes strings as an argument.

---

edit: the d3 reference at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append states

> selection.append(name)
>      ... ... ...
>   "The name may be specified either as a constant string or as a function that returns the DOM element to append."

Consequently I've tried

```
d3.select(el).append(function(){return svg;});
```

but that fails with a `Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.`

Comment: Well, why would you append an svg you already created?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `svg` is a selection, `svg.node()` returns the DOM element, e.g.:

`d3.select(el).append(function(){return svg.node();});`

(Mind you, I'm not certain that `svg` in your case is a true selection, but you could give it a try.)

Answer (score 4):

You might be better off using the regular `element.appendChild` function for this.

You can get a reference to your parent element using `d3.select(el).node()` then, you can call `.appendChild` on that, passing in `svg.node()` as the element to append.

So, all together:

```
d3.select(el).node().appendChild(svg.node());
```

Comment: Actually, I just tested it and the method suggested by @StephenThomas  seems to work just fine, so there's no need to fall back to the DOM method. I'll leave this up as an alternate anyways.